# Web service to web service calling in SAP PI

Tags: soap, wsdl, sap-pi, sap-xi

I am doing a scenario called webservice to webservice in SAP PI.
I followed the following URL:
http://saptechnical.com/Tutorials/XI/WebService2WS/Page9.htm.

I created the WSDL file at the end using tools->display WSDL.
I gave the following URL in the WSDL URL step:
`http://BCHSAP003:55000/sap/xi/engine?channel=:SOAP_Request_BS_1:BS_Sender`.

The WSDL URL that got created in the file is :
`http://bchsap003:55000/sap/xi/engine?channel=:soap_request_bs_1:BS_Sender&amp;`.

When I open the URL in browser it is giving the following:

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP:Header></SOAP:Header>
    <SOAP:Body>
        <SOAP:Fault xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <faultcode>SOAP:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Empty HTTP request received</faultstring>
            <faultactor>http://sap.com/xi/XI/Message/30</faultactor>
            <detail>
                <SAP:Error xmlns:SAP="http://sap.com/xi/XI/Message/30" SOAP:mustUnderstand="1">
                    <SAP:Category>XIProtocol</SAP:Category>
                    <SAP:Code area="MESSAGE">EMPTY_HTTP_REQUEST_RECEIVED</SAP:Code>
                    <SAP:P1 />
                    <SAP:P2 />
                    <SAP:P3 />
                    <SAP:P4 />
                    <SAP:AdditionalText />
                    <SAP:Stack>
                        Empty HTTP query received; message processing not possible
                    </SAP:Stack>
                </SAP:Error>
            </detail>
        </SOAP:Fault>
    </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

When I am testing the WSDL file from my SOAP UI, it is not returning any response.

I changed the authentication in SOAP to preemptive, and after that getting the following response:

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP:Body>
        <SOAP:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>System Error</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <s:SystemError xmlns:s="http://sap.com/xi/WebService/xi2.0">
                    <context />
                    <code>MESSAGE.GENERAL</code>
                    <text />
                </s:SystemError>
            </detail>
        </SOAP:Fault>
    </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

I think there is some issue with the WSDL.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: you need to check the system logs

Answer (score 0):

I was writing the hostname in the target URL which PI was not able to recognise.
I changed it to IP.
It's working fine now.